# Getting External IP

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to get the external IP of a user, so that I can save it to their user file. But I can't find any way to do it. I've tried doing:

```
Private Function getExternalIP() As Net.IPAddress
    Using wc As New Net.WebClient
        Return Net.IPAddress.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.DownloadData("http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp")))
    End Using
End Function
```

But I keep getting a formatException saying the "ip is invalid"

Comment: We would need to know what the response from http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp looks like.

Comment: This from 2012 works fine as of this comment - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/452024/Getting-the-External-IP-Address

Answer (score 0):

here is some code, you may want to add a check to ensure it is not run too often:

```
 Private Shared Function GetExternalIP() As String

    Dim Response As String = String.Empty

    Try

        Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim whatIsMyIp As String = "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"
        Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(myWebClient.OpenRead(whatIsMyIp))

        Response = file.ReadToEnd()
        file.Close()
        file.Dispose()
        myWebClient.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response = "Could not confirm External IP Address" & vbCrLf & ex.Message.ToString
    End Try

    Return Response

End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting this in the intermediate window "A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll" and this in the users file "Could not confirm External IP Address
The remote name could not be resolved: 'automation.whatismyip.com'"

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this function. It seems to work a lot better than using an API. I found it when I was searching for it. it's come from here:

http://www.guideushow.com/code-snippet/get-external-ip-function-vb-net-c/

```
Function GetExternalIP() As IPAddress
    Dim lol As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim str As String = lol.DownloadString("http://www.ip-adress.com/")
    Dim pattern As String = "<h2>My IP address is: (.+)</h2>"
    Dim matches1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, pattern)
    Dim ip As String = matches1(0).ToString
    ip = ip.Remove(0, 21)
    ip = ip.Replace("</h2>", "")
    ip = ip.Replace(" ", "")
    Return IPAddress.Parse(ip)
End Function
```